# Change the DocumentRoot folder in apache cause permission issue

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, permissions, document-root

I installed a LAMP in my AWS EC2 instance. The DocumentRoot folder is in /var/www/html. What I did is to copy the html folder into my /home/ec2-user and rename it to www. Then the DocumentRoot is changed to /home/ec2-user/www. Of course the https.conf is changed accordingly. Here it is:

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/home/ec2-user/www"

<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    #AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all    
</Directory>

#<Directory "/var/www/html">
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/www">
```

The problem is I got the following error message after I restart the https service.

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

The owner and the permission is the same for both folder. Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I searched in stack overflow and found some similar issues. But none of them work for me. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Was that an error message you got in the console when restarting the service, or is this displayed by apache when requesting an URL from it in thr browser?

Comment: (Oh, and it's off-topic here, you should head over to ServerFault)

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: Mind to show us the full config file then? at least the `<Directory "/home/ec2-user/www">` container.

Comment: I found the problem. I should also set the permission for ec2-user directory too. Everything's fine after I run "chmod 755 ec2-user".

Comment: Thank your Johannes H. anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is the user apache runs as, is not ec2-user.

You *could* change it, but putting your doc root inside of the ec2-user's home directory is probably not a good idea. More then likely everything you do on your instance is as the ec2-user (who is a sudoer and has access to pretty much everything), so if someone was to compromise a script that apache is running, they would literally have full control over your instance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll consider your opinions.